# Assigning a boolean value from an "if ... in" statement in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am just starting on Python from a PHP background. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way in assigning a variable the result of an "if ... in" statement?

I currently do

```
is_holiday = False
if now_date in holidays:
    is_holiday = True
```

To me it looks like an unnecessary amount of code line or is this the absolute minimum and meets python style guides?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `if ... in` statement. `in` is an infix operator that produces a boolean value. The `if` statement requires a boolean value to switch on; in this case, that value is provided by the `in` operator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
is_holiday = now_date in holidays
```

Comment: That's right, but it only fits this particular case, doesn't it?

Comment: @gravetii: It fits with *any* expression producing a boolean.

Comment: Not really, basically any `var = False; if boolean_expr(): var = True;` can be replaced by `var = boolean_expr()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

`is_holiday = True if now_date in holidays else False`

or just `is_holiday = now_date in holidays`.

Comment: Ugh, why even *mention* a conditional expression when the *expression itself* produces a boolean?

Comment: Or use `is_holiday = True if (True if now_date in holidays else False) else False`... :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, just come up with that first , maybe it's new info to the OP and is more general ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I'd **never** use a conditional expression to produce a boolean. Use `bool()` if your expression doesn't produce a boolean value directly, instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what about cases like `a=1 if b>1 else -1`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: That's not producing a boolean. That's the normal use case for a conditional expression.